# Arch Linux SSH access, but no internet (eth0/DHCP)

Tags: ssh, ethernet, archlinux, internet

I have an original Raspberry Pi, on which I just installed Arch Linux. I followed the guide [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi).

I plugged the Pi into my router with an ethernet cable and I am able to access it via SSH. However, I can't seem to get an internet connection to the outside world. When I ping google.com I get output like this:

```
PING google.com(ord31s21-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:808::200e)) 56 data bytes
From 2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4 (2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: No route
From 2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4 (2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4) icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: No route
From 2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4 (2604:2d80:c028:8198:b675:eff:fe37:55d4) icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: No route
```

When I curl google.com I get a 301 response:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

The contents of my /etc/systemd/network/wired.network are:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

I have tried running dhcpcd eth0 and that seems to work. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. You *are* getting to the outside world, over IPv6 no less!

Google gives you a 301 because you are probably not sending all the necessary HTML headers for the GFE (Google Front End) to decide where to forward your request, so it's sending you back to www.google.com.

Comment: You're right. One more question — what is the whole "no routes" thing when I try pinging a website?